# Parsing cells and format string

Tags: string, excel

I need to create lot of SQL insert statements, using an excel datasheet.
Suppose I have the following excel:

```
A             B              C
-----    ----    -----  >>>>  ----
TE            ZZ           Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('&A1', '&B1');
TT            CC           Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('&A2', '&B3');
EX            FF           Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('&A3', '&B3');
```

My output should be:

```
       Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('TE', 'ZZ');
       Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('TT', 'CC');
       Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('EX', 'FF');
```

I'm unable to achieve it. I tryied with **&A1, =A1**.

Should I split my whole string and use concatenate?

```
Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('
A1
', '
B1
');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column C should have formulas like this:

```
="Insert into TABLE (CODE, VAL) Values   ('"&A1&"', '"&B1&"');"
```

Comment: thank you. You miss a commercial & in the second replace statement '"&B2&"'